# force close error occurs in my java class when I want to display it in XML Layout

Tags: android

I've no idea why there's a force close error occurs.

I would like to display the code in my XML Layout.
However, there's an force close error occurs.
I'm not sure what's the problem with it.

Here is my logcat error.

```
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fambond/com.example.fambond.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at com.example.fambond.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:144)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
07-27 15:44:51.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> psi;

      public TextView psi_text;

    TextView weather;
     ImageView image;
     private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     class MyWeather{


      String conditiontext;
      String conditiontemp;
      String conditiondate;



      public String forecastToString(){

       return 
         conditiontext + "\n" + "        "  + conditiontemp + "°C"  ;

      } 
     }

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);
            image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            psi = new ArrayList<String>();  


            psi_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.psi_text);

            try {

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;                 

                    NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("psi");
                    Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                    websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                    psi.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());           

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }



            String temp = Html.fromHtml(psi.get(0)).toString(); 
            String a[] = temp.split("\\)");
            psi_text.setText(""+a[0]+")");


            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                 @Override
                   public void run() {
                    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
                          Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

                          final MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                              @Override
                                 public void run() {
                                  weather.setText(weatherResult.forecastToString());
                                 }});

                               }});
                                    myThread.start();
                                }

     private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

         MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

            //<yweather:condition.../>
         Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);


         String weatherCode = conditionNode.getAttributes()
               .getNamedItem("code")
               .getNodeValue()
               .toString();

         // thunderstorms
         if(weatherCode.equals("4")){

             mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
                    // Views

                     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                }
            });
         }

         //isolated thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("37")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }


         //scattered thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("38")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //scattered thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("39")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //thundershowers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("45")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //isolated thundershowers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("47")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //drizzle
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("9")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //showers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("11")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
                        }
                    });
                }

 //showers
else if ( weatherCode.equals("12")) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
        }
    });
}

         //scattered showers
else if ( weatherCode.equals("40")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
            }
        });
    }

         //hail
else if ( weatherCode.equals("17")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hail);
            }
        });
    }


         //mixed rain and hail
else if ( weatherCode.equals("35")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hail);
            }
        });
    }

         //foggy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("20")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //haze
else if ( weatherCode.equals("21")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //smoky
else if ( weatherCode.equals("22")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //windy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("24")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.windy);
            }
        });
    }

         //cloudy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("26")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //fair (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("33")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //fair (day)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("34")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //partly cloudy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("44")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //mostly cloudy (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("27")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //partly cloudy (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("29")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //mostly cloudy (day)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("28")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }


         //partly cloudy (day)
    else if ( weatherCode.equals("30")) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_cloudy);
                }
            });
        }




         //clear(night)
    else if ( weatherCode.equals("31")) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.moon);
                }
            });
        }


         //sunny
    else {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunny);
                }
            });
        }




         myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
       .getNamedItem("text")
       .getNodeValue()
       .toString();

         myWeather.conditiontemp = conditionNode.getAttributes()
                   .getNamedItem("temp")
                   .getNodeValue()
                   .toString();




     return myWeather; 
    }

    private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){

     Document dest = null;
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
       DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder parser;

     try {
      parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes())); 
     } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     return dest; 
    }

    private String QueryYahooWeather(){

     String qResult = "";
     String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c";

     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

     try {
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

      if (httpEntity != null){
       InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
       Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
       BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

       String stringReadLine = null;

       while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n"); 
       }

       qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
      } 
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     return qResult; 
    }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Recommended" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Neighbourhood" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:text="Museum" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:text="Sports" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Location:" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Education" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="Festival" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="Performing Arts" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="By Month" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_above="@+id/weather"
               android:layout_marginLeft="235dp"              
              />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/psi_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/weather"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which one is line no 144 in this?

Comment: my code works well in another project.
however, when I transfer it over,
the error thus occurs

Answer (score 0):

Logcat tells that :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Your array list,
 psi doesnot contain any item and you are trying to get items from that. Hence the ForceClose.

This line causes the problem :  `String temp = Html.fromHtml(psi.get(0)).toString();`

Make sure before you try to get data, check whether its size is greater than 0 or not.

Comment: Hi,
when I run this code in another project,
it works perfectly fine..

But I got no idea why when I transfer it,
error will occurs

Answer (score 0):

I think it is crashing here

```
String temp = Html.fromHtml(psi.get(0)).toString();
```

You need to make sure that below `for` loop executes properly

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       
    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;                 

    NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("psi");
    Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
    websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

    psi.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());           
}
```

In case this `for` loop is not executing even once, then you `psi` array will have 0 size so you can't access the `0th index` like you are trying to do.

Comment: hmm,
so what should I change?

Comment: Are you able to get these things properly? Please debug once
`Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");`

Comment: the whole code is actually working perfectly like I once said just now.
However,
it just that when I transfer it over to another project.
It fails

Comment: so check the setting of this project? Have you included the required android permissions in your manifest file? It is not going to help if you do not debug your code once. If the code is working fine in another project then mostly it is the project settings which can be causing the issue.

Comment: great...where was the actual issue? :-)

Comment: internet permission /=

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

This is the array bounds, and a good check under your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add Internet permission in the Android manifest.